# Modulus issue connection to Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am following a CRUD application by this website: https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-restful-api-using-node-and-express-4.

When I try to use the server it gives me this message error:

```
[devops@localhost CRUD - Node.Js Express.JS & MongoDb]$ node server.js
Aplicação executando na porta 8080

/home/devops/Documentos/Labs/CRUD - Node.Js Express.JS & MongoDb/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:242
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^
Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND waffle.modulusmongo.net waffle.modulusmongo.net:27017
    at errnoException (dns.js:27:10)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:78:26)
[devops@localhost CRUD - Node.Js Express.JS & MongoDb]$
```

P.S.: I am using a internal proxy (because I am developing this tutorial on the Company network)

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve the problem... the question is that my proxy and firewall is blocking the external connection.... so I decided create a local database... now is working pretty good! :)